# How to safely destruct class with smart pointer to incomplete object type?

Tags: c++

I'm concerned about using an incomplete type with a smart pointer and how the pointer is deleted. Is the following code safe? I don't think it would be, as main.cpp would generate Farm's default destructor which wouldn't see the complete type. To make it safe, I think I should create a non-inline destructor which sees the complete type. Is that correct?

Also is it the same if I used `std::vector<Cow>` in Farm instead?

farm.h

```
class Cow;

struct Farm
{
    Farm();
    // ~Farm();
    std::unique_ptr<Cow> cow;
};
```

farm.cpp

```
#include "cow.h"
// cow now complete

Farm::Farm()
{
    cow.reset(new Cow);
}

// Farm::~Farm() {}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "farm.h"

int main()
{
    Farm farm;
}
```

Edit: I tried to compile with Visual Studio without the destructor and it says error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type. I guess that answers my question.

Comment: Note that with auto_ptr, the code compiles :-/

Comment: @Jarod: Yes, and silently does the wrong thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595471/does-the-gotw-101-solution-actually-solve-anything

Comment: @Jarod42: With `auto_ptr` the code is bad, because the default destructor of `Farm` uses the destructor of `auto_ptr`, which just does `delete` with the incomplete type `Cow`. This has UB if the actual destructor of `Cow` is non-trivial, and is valid otherwise. Since the compiler can't tell which it is (not having the definition of `Cow`), it goes ahead and outputs the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your code should compile (and it doesn't in gcc)

`std::unique_ptr<Cow>` uses `std::default_delete<Cow>`, and `std::default_delete<Cow>::operator()` should fail to instantiate for an incomplete type `Cow`.

See also [Is it true that a unique_ptr declaration, unlike a auto_ptr declaration, is well-defined when its template type is of an incomplete type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764952)

So you're right: you need to ensure that `default_delete<Cow>::operator()` is instantiated somewhere that the `Cow` type is complete. Which means the destructor of `Farm` needs to be defined in such a place.

I've just noticed that your subject says "smart pointer", while the question specifies `unique_ptr`. The answer would be different for a `shared_ptr`, since `std::shared_ptr<Cow>::reset()` is a function template that captures the (static) type of the pointer passed to it and stores a deleter. So with `shared_ptr` all you need is that the call to `reset` has the complete type `Cow` -- the location of the destructor doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. But when does shared_ptr need the complete type?

Comment: @NeilKirk: at the points where the deleter is inferred: -- `reset()`, constructors and assignment operators from pointer types. If you specify the deleter in those cases then `shared_ptr` doesn't need the complete type ever, only your custom deleter does. And of course anyone who uses the result of `operator->` and `operator*` ;-)

Comment: `shared_ptr` works with incomplete type, but `unique_ptr` does not

Answer (score 1):

The default destructor for `Farm` will include a desructor for the `unique_ptr`, which will include a destructor for `Cow`. This call will be done even if there's no definition available at the time of compiling. The linker will be expected to connect things up after the fact.

Comment: I tried it and I get compiler error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type