# include a class that has std::unique_ptr<T> as a field, while "T" is incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom, incomplete-type

I created a tiny test case for `std::unique<B>` with incomplete type `B`.

**Test.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
class B;   //<--- compile error here
class Test{
    std::unique_ptr<B> bPtr;   
    //#1 need to move destructor's implementation to .cpp
    public: ~Test();
};
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"
class B{};
Test::~Test(){}  //move here because it need complete type of B
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
   Test test;
   return 0;
}
```

I got this error:-

> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:65:22: error: invalid
>   application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'B'

As far as I understand, the compiler tells me that  `B` is an incomplete type (in `main.cpp`), so it can't delete `B` properly.

However, in my design, I want `main.cpp` to **not** have complete type of `B`.
Very roughly speaking, it is a pimpl.

Is there a good workaround?

Here is some similar questions, but none suggest a clean workaround.

- [C++ Pimpl Idiom Imcomplete Type using std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786387/c-pimpl-idiom-imcomplete-type-using-stdunique-ptr)  tells to move destructor to `.cpp` (`#1`)
- [std::unique_ptr with an incomplete type won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile)  shows an ugly workaround by encapsulating `std::unique_ptr<B>` with non-template class.  Then, manually move the destructor of the encapsulator to `.cpp`. (`#2`)
- [std::unique_ptr<T> incomplete type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420015/stdunique-ptrt-incomplete-type-error) suggest to provide custom deleter (function).   (`#3`)

Is `std::unique_ptr` not a right tool?
Should I create my own `unique_ptr`?  I may use `#3` as a guide.

### **Edit:**

**Kerrek SB** has practically solved all problems in the code.  Thank a lot!

The remaining question is that :-
Should I create my own `unique_ptr` to remove this restriction?
Is it possible? - I guess it is possible, and I am trying to code it now.

Comment: The constructor(s) need to move to the .cpp file, too.

Comment: @Kerrek SB   Oh no!  Shameful me.  Many thank.  .... adding an empty constructor (and implement to .cpp) make it compile .... I will test it more.  ..... After testing in my complex program, it works!  Thank!