# Is it valid for a C++ compiler to implicitly instantiate ALL member functions of a template class?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, c++builder

Suppose I have a public class and a private implementation class (e.g. PIMPL pattern), and I wish to wrap the private class with a template smart pointer class with a checked delete, as follows:

**`PublicClass.h`**

```
class PrivateClass;

// simple smart pointer with checked delete
template<class X> class demo_ptr
{
public:
    demo_ptr (X* p) : the_p(p) { }
    ~demo_ptr () {
        // from boost::checked_delete: don't allow compilation of incomplete type
        typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(X)? 1: -1 ];
        (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
        delete the_p;
    }
private:
    X* the_p;
};

// public-facing class that wishes to wrap some private implementation guts
class PublicClass
{
public:
    PublicClass();
    ~PublicClass();

private:
    demo_ptr<PrivateClass> pvt;
};
```

**`PublicClass.cpp`**

```
#include "PublicClass.h"

class PrivateClass
{
public:
    // implementation stuff goes here...
    PrivateClass() {}
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PublicClass::PublicClass() : pvt(new PrivateClass()) {}

PublicClass::~PublicClass() {}
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include "PublicClass.h"

int main()
{
    PublicClass *test = new PublicClass();
    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles successfully on Visual C++ 2008, but fails to compile on an old version of C++ Builder.  In particular, `main.cpp` does not compile because `demo_ptr<PrivateClass>::~demo_ptr` is being instantiated by `main.cpp`, and that destructor won't compile because it can't do `sizeof` on an incomplete type for `PrivateClass`.  Clearly, it is not useful for the compiler to be instantiating `~demo_ptr` in the consuming `main.cpp`, since it will never be able to generate a sensible implementation (seeing as how `~PrivateClass` is not accessible).  (`PublicClass.cpp` compiles fine on all tested compilers.)

My question is: what does the C++ standard say about implicit instantiation of a template class's member functions?  Might it be one of the following?  In particular, *has this changed over the years?*

- If a template class is used, then all member functions of the class should be implicitly instantiated - whether used or not?
- Or: template class functions should only be implicitly instantiated one at a time if actually used.  If a particular template class function isn't used, then it shouldn't be implicitly instantiated - even if other template class functions are used and instantiated.

It seems clear that the second case is the case *today* because this same pattern is used with PIMPL and `unique_ptr` with its checked delete, but maybe that was not the case in the past?  Was the first case acceptable compiler behavior in the past?

Or in other words, was the compiler buggy, or did it accurately follow the C++98 standard, and the standard changed over the years?

(Fun fact: if you remove the checked delete in C++ Builder, and have function inlining turned off, the project will happily compile.  `PublicClass.obj` will contain a correct `~demo_ptr` implementation, and `main.obj` will contain an incorrect `~demo_ptr` implementation with undefined behavior.  The function used will depend on the order in which these files are fed to the linker.)

**UPDATE:  This is due to a compiler bug, as noted by Andy Prowl, which is still not fixed in C++ Builder XE8.  I've reported the bug to Embarcadero:**  [bcc32 compiler causes undefined behavior when using std::auto_ptr with PIMPL idiom because template instantiation rules do not follow C++ spec](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13126)

Comment: BTW `demo_ptr` violates the rule of 3 -- you'll want to fix that before it bites you with double deletion.

Comment: "Old compiler" and the symptoms you've stated reakes of: likely a compiler bug.  To my knowledge there is not a single C++ compiler that is fully compliant with the language spec. The last version of clang is probably your best bet, but understand if you're using a really old compiler, you can expect really old and buggy behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt: understood; this is just a pedantic test case shortened for brevity.  In reality I just use auto_ptr.

Comment: Why do you use `auto_ptr`?

Comment: @Yakk: The code already widely uses it, and the runtime library doesn't yet support unique_ptr.  We'll switch someday.

Comment: @ildjarn: So that the compiler doesn't autogenerate a destructor that has undefined behavior, which would happen on any C++ compiler if you left this out.

Comment: @ildjarn: Really?  Have you even tried implementing the PIMPL pattern with a smart pointer?  `unique_ptr` will throw a compile error if you use it wrong, but other smart pointer classes such as `auto_ptr` will happily and silently compile code with undefined behavior.  Why not tell Herb Sutter to start over with a good book?  http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/ read item #2.

Comment: @James : And what does that have to do with an empty/pointless non-trivial destructor?

Comment: @ildjarn: Quoting link, since you didn't bother to read it: "You still need to write the visible class’ destructor yourself and define it out of line in the implementation file, even if ... it’s the same as what the compiler would generate ... unique_ptr’s destructor requires a complete type in order to invoke delete ... By writing it yourself in the implementation file, you force it to be defined in a place where impl is already defined, and this successfully prevents the compiler from trying to automatically generate the destructor on demand in the caller’s code where impl is not defined."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a template class is used, then all member functions of the class should be implicitly instantiated - whether used or not?

**No**, this is definitely not the case. Per Paragraph 14.7.1/10 of the C++11 Standard (and Paragraph 14.7.1/9 of the C++03 Standard) very clearly specifies:

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, a **non-virtual
>   member function**, a member class, or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation.

As for when instantiation is required, Paragraph 14.7.1/2 specifies:

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly
>   specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated **when the specialization is referenced
>   in a context that requires the member definition to exist**; [...]

This is certainly not the case if a member function is never referenced.

---

Unfortunately, I can't provide an official reference on what the rules were before C++03, but to the best of my knowledge the same "lazy" instantiation mechanism was adopted in C++98.

Comment: The member function certainly is referenced, from the automatically-generated portions of `PublicClass::~PublicClass` as it invokes member destructors such as `demo_ptr::~demo_ptr`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I did not say the member function is not referenced. I merely answered the question about what the Standard mandates: *"This is certainly not the case **if a member function is never referenced**."*

Comment: Ok, glad you understand.  I still think the clarification is useful for other readers.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for with quotations from the standard.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr` is a funny beast.

Unlike `auto_ptr`, which called the destructor of the referenced object from the smart pointer destructor, `unique_ptr::~unique_ptr` merely invokes a deleter function which has been previously stored.

The deleter function is stored in the `unique_ptr` *constructor*, which is called for each and every `PublicClass` constructor.  The user-defined constructor is defined in a context where `PrivateClass::~PrivateClass` is available, so that's ok.  But what about other implicitly-generated `PublicClass` constructors, such as a move constructor?  They're generated at the point of use; they also need to initialize the `unique_ptr` member, meaning they must supply a deleter.  But without `PrivateClass::~PrivateClass`, they can't.

Wait, your question mentions `unique_ptr`, but your code isn't using it.  Weird...

Even when the destructor is invoked from the smart pointer destructor, it can still be ODR-used from the containing class *constructors*.  This is for exception-safety -- the constructor needs the capability to tear down a partially-constructed class, which includes destruction of members.

It looks like C++Builder may be generating a `PublicClass` copy or more constructor, even though your program doesn't use it.  That doesn't fall afoul of the rule Andy mentioned, because `PublicClass` isn't a template.  I think the compiler is entitled to generate a defaulted copy constructor for `PublicClass` when it processes the class definition, since you can't provide an out-of-class definition for a defaulted member.  Respecting the rule of three for `demo_ptr` will preclude `PublicClass` having a copy constructor, and therefore may solve your problem.

Comment: But C++03 and C++11 carefully distinguish between an implicitly declared special member function and an implicitly defined special member function, and the definition is not required unless used.  Not sure if this was the case in C++98.

Comment: @BenVoigt: "The deleter function is stored in the auto_ptr constructor".  auto_ptr::auto_ptr(X*) does no such thing... it just stores the pointer, nothing more - no destructor function pointer at any rate.  Maybe you were thinking of shared_ptr which does store a deleter?

Comment: @James: Actually it was `unique_ptr` I meant.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `unique_ptr` doesn't store it at the constructor, either.  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html says: "You can safely use unique_ptr<A> ... as long as A is a complete type wherever ~unique_ptr<A> is instantiated".  I found a stack overflow answer earlier that covered this as well, though I forget the link.  Unlike ~auto_ptr, ~unique_ptr will do this checked deleter trick to get a compile error.

Comment: Ah, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile