# Why does boost::scoped_ptr prevent PIMPL idiom with BCB6?

Tags: c++, c++builder-6, boost-smart-ptr

I'm trying to use a `boost::scoped_ptr` with my implementation class that is visible only in the cpp file of the containing class. The containing class has an explicitly defined destructor (that isn't inline), but my compiler (Borland C++ 5.6.4) fails to compile.

If I use `boost::shared_ptr` instead, the same example compiles and runs as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** sorry for forgetting showing the source code, compiler error, and (expected) output here it is:

### Source code

File `check_shared.cpp`:

```
// shortened.
#include "SmartPtrTest.h"
void check_shared()
{
    Containing t;
}
```

File `SmartPtrTest.h`:

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

class Impl;
#define smart_ptr boost::scoped_ptr

class Containing: private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    Containing();
    ~Containing();
private:
    smart_ptr<Impl> impl;
};
```

File `SmartPtrTest.cpp`:

```
#include "SmartPtrTest.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Impl {
public:
    Impl() {
        cout << "ctr Impl" << endl;
    }
    ~Impl() {
        cout << "dtr Impl" << endl;
    }
};

Containing::Containing(): impl(new Impl)
{
    cout << "ctr Containing" << endl;
}

Containing::~Containing()
{
    cout << "dtr Containing" << endl;
}
```

### The compiler error

...is something like `undefined structure 'Impl'` (it's German: *Undefinierte Struktur 'Impl'*). When compiling the file `check_shared.cpp` the compiler stops in the file `boost/checked_delete.hpp` in the `typedef` of this function:

```
template<class T> inline void checked_delete(T * x)
{
    // intentionally complex - simplification causes regressions
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
    (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
    delete x;
}
```

### The output (expected)

This output I'm getting when using `boost::share_ptr`, showing that ctr and dtr are called as expected.

```
ctr Impl
ctr Containing
dtr Containing
dtr Impl
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - not showing us the code or the error message (or describing the unexpected behaviour, or whatever problem you're having).

Comment: You're using a 13 year old compiler. Try with a modern compiler instead? :)

Comment: @jalf Absolutely. That's what I'm trying: getting rid of it, but the project still has to be maintained.

Comment: The error message is still incomplete. The part of interest is the function that triggers the deletion of the scoped_ptr in the first place.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I tried to provide more details about the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

This is most definitely due to a compiler bug.  Unfortunately it still exists in C++ Builder XE8.  See this related problem here, and the answer from Andy Prowl:  [Is it valid for a C++ compiler to implicitly instantiate ALL member functions of a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891106/is-it-valid-for-a-c-compiler-to-implicitly-instantiate-all-member-functions-of)

Problem reported to Embarcadero here:  [bcc32 compiler causes undefined behavior when using std::auto_ptr with PIMPL idiom because template instantiation rules do not follow C++ spec](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13126)

If you can use one of the newer clang-based compilers from Embarcadero, you should be ok.  My test case passes in the 64-bit clang compiler.

**UPDATE:**  We've worked around the issue by writing our own smart pointer class that's similar to `unique_ptr` in that it contains a `checked_delete` function that is not implemented inline inside the class.  Instead, you have to explicitly instantiate the `checked_delete` function inside ONE translation unit that also contains the private class implementation.  A macro is used to help with that.  That is:

```
template<class X> class unique_ptr_bcc32 {
    // Deletes the object using operator delete:
    private: static void checked_delete(X* p);
    // <snip>
}
```

Later, in a CPP file:

```
class PIMPL { /* snip implementation */ };

// You can simplify this by way of a macro:
template <> void unique_ptr_bcc32<PIMPL>::checked_delete(PIMPL* p) {
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[sizeof(PIMPL) ? 1 : -1];
    static_cast<void>(sizeof(type_must_be_complete));
    delete p;
}
```

This leaves no room for funny business by the compiler when it comes to template instantiation and deleting.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as the "implementation" class is complete at any point at which the smart pointer might be destroyed. This happens not just in the destructor, but in the constructors - these have to destroy the pointer member if they exit due to an exception.

So make sure that your constructors and destructor are defined in the source file, after the implementation class's definition.

(This is based on a guess you get a compilation error due to trying to destroy an incomplete type. If you get a different error, or unexpected runtime behaviour, or the change doesn't fix it, then please update the question to demonstrate the actual problem.)

Comment: I've added the code, would you please have a look at it again? Thanks.

Comment: @Wolf: The code you've posted works for me (when I add the missing `#include "SmartPtrTest.h"` and `main` function). Either your ancient compiler is doing something weird (perhaps looking for the definition in the context of the template definition instead of the instantiation point), or the code you've posted isn't the code you're compiling.

Comment: Thanks for checking. So it seems to be a compiler issue, maybe it is due to some flaws in the implementation of the STL shipped with BCB6...

Comment: @Wolf: BCB6 did not ship with Boost included. The code you showed does not use BCB's STL at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was not sure about this. I thought that boost itself uses some elements of the STL, I didn't analyse the scoped_ptr template yet.