# unique_ptr pimpl and incomplete types

Tags: c++, c++11, pimpl-idiom

**This is not a dupe of [std::unique_ptr with an incomplete type won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile)**.

Consider the code below:

```
#include <memory>

struct X
{
    X();
    ~X();    

    struct Impl; 
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> up_;
};

struct Impl {}; // fully visible here

X::X() : up_{nullptr}{}
X::~X() = default;

int main()
{
    X x;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0aeb3e19a3cde72)

gcc/clang both spit an error saying that `Impl` is incomplete. However, I provide a default destructor for `X` **after** `Impl` is fully visible, so IMO the code should compile. **Why doesn't?** Now comes the surprise: If I make `Impl` an inner class, i.e. define

```
struct X::Impl{};
```

instead, then [the code compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b9bf4ee239afa4c), even **without** providing a destructor. **Why is this happening? Shouldn't we provide such a default destructor, at least according to the link mentioned in the first line?**

Comment: Where you say "// fully visible here"; this is a different class from the one you declared in `struct X`.  Try moving `struct Impl;` before `struct X`.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think the structure should be fully visible in the destructor of `X`, which is defined after. At least that was my understanding of implementing PIMPL with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: In the code as originally written, there are two distinct unrelated things named `Impl`. You have `X::Impl` that's declared but never defined - that's the one `up_` uses. Then there's `::Impl` that's defined but never used. When you write `struct X::Impl{};` instead, you now have a single type named `X::Impl` that's declared and defined.

Comment: Split the code up into multiple cpp files as you normally would, and it [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f002dc469e859f10). If you uncomment the lines in the command edit box in my example, it'll compile. I think your second example above compiles because the end of the translation unit is a valid point of instantiation, so the `unique_ptr` destructor is not instantiated until then (not sure about this part).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ohhh I see, I though `struct Impl;` is a forward declaration and will be considered as outside the class, but is treated by the compiler as `X::Impl`. You are right, if I move e.g. `struct Impl;` above `struct X{}` then it works.

Comment: @Praetorian I believe you're right, I haven't tried splitting in multiple cpp/h files, although I clearly remember that we **need** to provide the destructor after in that case. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two different structs named `Impl`.

```
struct X
{
    struct Impl; // Here you declare X::Impl
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> up_;  // Here you create a pointer to a X::Impl
};

struct Impl {};  // Here you declare and define ::Impl

...

int main()
{
    X x;  // Here X::Impl is still incomplete
}
```