# std::list<std::unique_ptr>: empty initializer list vs. default constructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, c++17

The code

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class B;
class A {
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

int main()
{
    A x;
    return 0;
}
```

obviously compiles. It doesn't link because `A::A()` and `A::~A()` are missing, but that is expected and alright. Changing

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;
```

which is supposed to call the `std::list`'s standard constructor

```
list() : list(Allocator()) {}
```

(C++14 and up) to

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs{};
```

which is supposed to call <s>list(std::initializer_list, const Allocator & = Allocator());</s>
the default constructor too.
(Thanks to *Nicol Bolas*, who rightly referred to [over.match.list] 13.3.1.7)
gives the following error with **c++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010** and the **--std=c++17** parameter:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = B]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:236:17:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = B; _Dp = std::default_delete<B>]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:106:12:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::destroy(_Up*) [with _Up = std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<B> >; _Tp = std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<B> >]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/list.tcc:75:4:   required from ‘void std::__cxx11::_List_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_clear() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<B>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<B> >]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:446:17:   required from ‘std::__cxx11::_List_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::~_List_base() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<B>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<B> >]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:507:11:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:74:22: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘B’
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
                      ^
```

Which barks about the type of `B` being incomplete. My question is:

Why does the `initializer_list` constructor need the complete type of `B` for an empty initializer list?

Pointers to the relevant parts of the standard are always appreciated.

Comment: In case of exception you might have to destroy B, so its definition is required.

Comment: In other words, the destructor must also be fully defined, and for this the `unique_ptr` needs a full type, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile @Jarod42 You should post an answer, as this is a good question and not so obvious.

Comment: FYI: `std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs{};` will call the *default* constructor. In accord with 13.3.1.7 of the C++14 standard, if an empty braced-init-list is passed to a type that has a default constructor, then that is what will be called.

Comment: `std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;` should call the default constructor too, right? Why doesn't the one with the `{}` work, then?

Comment: @apriori As a member declaration, `std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;` doesn't call any constructor.

Comment: @T.C. It is a non-static data member definition, see [basic.def] 3.1 (2). [class.init] 12.6 (1) says: "When no initializer is specified for an object of (possibly cv-qualified) class type (or array thereof), or the
initializer has the form (), the object is initialized as specified in 8.5.", [decl.init] 8.5 (12) says "If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized". [dcl.init] 8.5 (7.1) goes on: if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for T is called [...]"

Comment: By your logic, you can't have any non-static data member of a type without a default constructor, which is plainly nonsense.

Comment: @T.C. I quote the standard with "[...] an object of (possibly cv-qualified) class type (or array thereof) [...]". Do you have an example of a non-static data member of class type without a default constructor? `struct X { X() = delete; }; class A { X x; }; int main() { A a; return 0; }` certainly doesn't work.

Comment: You really need help to think up an example??? `struct X <% X(int); %>; class A <% X x; public: A() : x(0) <%%> %> a; ` I think you should be learning the language first, before trying to language-lawyer it.

Comment: Now you're ignoring the "When no initializer is specified [...]" part. I thought it would be clear from the context when I wrote my follow-up comment. Thanks for participating, but with that rude attitude, I'd rather not keep on discussing with you.

Comment: And "no initializer is specified" in `X x;`, either. The only difference between this and your code is that I gave the constructor a definition and you didn't.

Comment: @T.C. Not in `X x;`, but after the constructor in a `ctor-initializer`. [class.base.init] 12.6.2 (1): "In the definition of a constructor for a class, **initializers** for direct and virtual base subobjects and **non-static data members** can be specified by a ctor-initializer". That is what you did, and that is why no *default* constructor was needed.

Comment: @apriori Correct, and not really relevant to my point. The point I'm trying to make is that `struct A { X x; A(); } a;` - which is your case - doesn't call `X`'s default constructor (or require that it has one). The constructor called for `x` entirely depends on how `A::A()` is written.

Comment: @T.C. Right, that is why I wrote "which is supposed to call the `std::list`'s standard constructor" in my question, so I assumed a definition of `A::A() = default`. Without that assumption, your comment "`std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;` doesn't call any constructor" could be interpreted as something along the lines of "`std::list<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;` doesn't call any *specific* constructor *, because the constructor called can be determined by an optional `ctor-initializer` specified in the ctor's implementation.*", which is IMO correct.

Comment: @apriori Well, it's not defaulted in your question (and in fact, if you did default it, you'd see the same errors in both cases!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've stepped onto the [bleeding edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeding_edge_technology).

This appears to be an active issue on the CWG (Core Working Group on the C++ committee).

[CWG 1396](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1396) appears to be concerned with this very issue.  This issue links to [CWG 1360](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1360) which says in part:

> The problem is exacerbated with class templates, since the current
>   direction of CWG is to instantiate member initializers only when they
>   are needed (see issue 1396).

In your example, the initializer of `bs` is *never* needed, and thus by the "direction" referred to above, *should* never be instantiated.  We just aren't there yet today.  Both of these issues have status *drafting*, meaning:  they're working on it.

FWIW, VS-2015 as reported at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net compiles (but of course does not link) this example.

Comment: Thank you very much Howard, that was exactly what I was looking for. Seems like this issue is unresolved for some time now.

Comment: CWG1396 is about class templates. `A` in OP's example is not a template. Default function arguments, for example, are not instantiated until needed for function templates, but do get checked for functions. `void f(double = "");` is ill-formed even if you never call it in a way that requires using the default argument.

Comment: @T.C.:  Perhaps.  I do not regularly sit in on the CWG meetings, and so am not intimately familiar with the issue.  I'm triggering on the title of CWG1396: "Deferred instantiation and checking of non-static data member initializers", which could be interpreted to pertain to the OP's code.  I welcome other theories, or insight from those who are better connected to the CWG than I am.