# Does a default member initializer for std::vector need a complete type?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Is it allowed, by the C++ standard, to use a default member initializer for a member variable of type `std::vector<A>` where `A` is an incomplete type?

My intuition is that a complete type should only be required at the point where the constructor, destructor, or assignment operators are defined.  In practice, it depends on which compiler is used and whether we're compiling with C++17 or C++20.  Which compiler is correct here?  What is causing the need for a complete type even when the constructor/destructor is not being defined in this compilation unit?

```
#include <vector>

struct A;

struct B
{
    //std::vector<A> vec; // okay
    std::vector<A> vec{}; // gcc13: fail; clang17: c++17 okay, c++20 fail
    B();
    ~B();
};

//struct A {}; // makes it work in gcc13, but not clang17
```

It may seem redundant to provide a default member initializer of this form.  However, there is a reason we have this pattern throughout our code: we use the `-Weffc++` warning because it catches a few bugs, but it has a side effect of forcing all member variables to be explicitly initialized either in the constructor initialization list or in a default member initializer.  The latter is more convenient.

Comment: I believe `-Weffc++` is a bit outdated for C++11 and later.  (Unless that warning has also been modernized, and I've not noticed.)

Comment: Related, but I'm still interested in a second opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090904/stdliststdunique-ptr-empty-initializer-list-vs-default-constructor

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975491/why-does-stdvector-work-with-incomplete-types-in-class-definitions

Comment: @davidhigh No, because I'm specifically wondering about how default member initializers interact with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the default member initializer is only evaluated when a constructor definition of `B` actually uses it (i.e. by not providing a initializer in its member initializer list), the default member initializer is still potentially-evaluated.

As such, the constructor of `std::vector<A>` is odr-used and will therefore be implicitly instantiated.

There are two points of instantiation for this implicit constructor instantiation: Immediately following the class definition, because that is the namespace definition from which the implicit instantiation is required, and at the end of the translation unit, because every implicit function template instantiation has a point of instantiation there.

Regardless of the definition `struct A {};` at the end, at the first point of instantiation `A` is incomplete and therefore the instantiation violates the precondition of `std::vector` which requires the element type to be complete when any member function is instantiated. That causes the program to have undefined behavior.

At the second point of instantiation `A` is complete iff you add the `struct A {};` definition, so there the precondition may be satisfied in that case.

However, if the instantiation is not valid at one point of instantiation, but is at the other, then the program is IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required). Essentially the compiler is permitted to chose at which of the two points it performs the instantiation. This explains why GCC happens to work with the definition of `A` at the end. The program effectively has undefined behavior regardless, since IFNDR has the same implication of not imposing any requirements on the compiler for handling the program.

So yes, using a default member initializer with `std::vector` requires the element type to be complete, but both compilers are behaving correctly in all configurations.

---

Technically, I am not sure that the standard correctly states whether or not the constructor is odr-used.

In [[basic.def.odr]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#def.odr-9.sentence-2) it refers to [dcl.init] to specify when constructors are odr-used, but that paragraph doesn't mention the term.

[[basic.def.odr]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#def.odr-8.sentence-2) applies to use in *expressions and conversions*, which I don't think can apply here since the constructor call is due to direct initialization, not any expression or conversion.

However, I am pretty sure the constructor is intended to be odr-used.

If you are interested in these specifics, I would recommend tagging the question [language-lawyer].