# unique_ptr incomplete type for forward declaration with default destructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, incomplete-type

My question is quite related to this thread:
[std::unique_ptr with an incomplete type won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile/9954553)

I understood the concept of incomplete type with unique_ptr and need to provide the default destructor for the holding class. However, I'm still getting following error:

```
 invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Game::Sprite’
```

Following is my simplified code. Please let me know if I'm still missing something here? :

```
/*
 * Game.h
 */
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "SDL.h"


class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void run();

    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

private:
    void setup();
    void loadResources();
    void createWorld();
    void loop();

    window mWindow;
    renderer mRenderer;
    class Sprite;
    using sprite = std::unique_ptr<Sprite>;
    sprite mPlayer;

    struct Resource {
        std::string name;
        std::string path;
    };
    enum class ResourceType {
        TEXTURE, IMAGE, AUDIO
    };

    std::unordered_map<ResourceType, Resource> mResourceList;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, texture> mTextureHolder;
};

/*
 * Game.cpp
 */
#include <Game.h>
 ...

#include "Sprite.h"

Game::Game() {
    ...
}


void Game::run() {
    setup();
    loadResources();
    loop();
}

void Game::setup() {
    ...
}

void Game::loadResources() {
    ...
}

void Game::createWorld() {
    ...
}

void Game::loop() {
    bool stop = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    while (!stop) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                stop = true;
            }
        }

        //clear screen
        SDL_RenderClear(mRenderer.get());

        //render texture
//      this gives error:
        mPlayer->renderFrame(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 0, 0);

        //update screen
        SDL_RenderPresent(mRenderer.get());
    }
}

//default destructor (tried explicit implmentation too)
Game::~Game() = default;

/*
 * Sprite.h
 */
#pragm once
#include "SDL.h"
#include <cstdint>

class Sprite {
public:
    Sprite(renderer renderer, texture texture, uint32_t width, uint32_t height);
    void renderFrame(uint32_t dstX, uint32_t dstY, uint32_t offsetX,
            uint32_t offsetY);
    void setTexture(texture texture);
private:
    renderer mRenderer;
    texture mTexture;
    uint32_t mWidth;
    uint32_t mHeight;
};

/*
 * Sprite.cpp
 */
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite(renderer renderer, texture texture, uint32_t width,
        uint32_t height) :
        mRenderer(renderer), mTexture(std::move(texture)), mWidth(width), mHeight(
                height) {
}

void Sprite::renderFrame(uint32_t dstX, uint32_t dstY, uint32_t offsetX,
        uint32_t offsetY) {
 ...
}

void Sprite::setTexture(texture texture) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: `class Game::Sprite` and `class Sprite` are two different classes. If you want to forward declare a class, do it at the same scope as the full definition will be (in this case at global scope it seems).

Comment: To put it in simpler terms, your `using` statement should be outside (in front of) of the `Game` class definition.

Comment: `using` is fine where it is, but `class Sprite;` forward declaration should be outside of `Game` class.

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen That indeed was the issue. However, now I'm getting following link errror:
undefined reference to `Sprite::renderFrame(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
Is it still related to this?

Comment: No, it's not related. Do you have both files in your build system? If you're sure build is correct, then see [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sure. Can you please add your earlier comment as answer so that I can mark it as correct solution?