# Inline destructor "causes" bad_alloc

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, virtual-destructor

I have encountered a strange bug in my program which was solved by making a destructor non-inline:

File a.h

```
class A {
    ...
    inline virtual ~A(){}
};
```

File b.h

```
class B : public A {
    ...
    virtual ~B(); // Defined in cpp file
};
```

Client code file.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
...
auto x = std::make_unique<B>();
```

The call to make_unique throws a bad_alloc exception. When I make ~A() non-inline and ~B() override, it stops throwing. Does anyone have any idea why it works? Another solution I found was to make printouts with cout in A and B's destructors. I have tried to simplify the relatively complex code as much as possible, so I must have left some crucial information out. What I want to know is what could have caused this strange behavior? Is overriding inline destructors with non-inline destructors somehow ambiguous?

Comment: *I have encountered a strange bug in my program which was solved by making a destructor non-inline:* -- Unless you can explain why a piece of code "fixes" the bug, consider this a non-fix.  All you really did was move code around, and doing that changes the binary image of the program.  Undefined behavior, if any, gets moved to a new location in the program, masking the bug.  I suggest you put the code back the way it was, and actually fix the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::unique\_ptr with an incomplete type won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that is a good point, that's why I consult SO. : )

Comment: @Quimby no, I wouldn't say that since by the time make_unique is called, the destructor of B is known. I updated the question, I seem to get the same error when instantiating a local unique_ptr.