# How to provide cpp class destructor member information in cython

Tags: cython

I have a scenario as follows,

c++ class

```
// Forward declared
class B;


class A {
   public:
   A();
   ~A(){val.reset();}

   std::unique_ptr<B> val;
}
```

cython

```
cdef cppclass A:
    A() except+
```

So, compiling this would gives error

*/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:22: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type*

and as per my knowledge this happens since there is no information about the class A destructor in cython definition and cython tends to use default destructor which and gets cornered because of unique_ptr with forward declared class.

Is there way to tackle this issue ?

Comment: And does it (if you create/destruct a variable of type A) get compiled as pure c++? I would be surprised.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9954518/5769463

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem is with destroying the unique_ptr. Cython is irrelevant here (as ead suggests)

Comment: @ead There will be definition for B somewhere in the library where the destructor has been defined, so C++ will compile.

Comment: @DavidW as per one of those solutions, I have a destructor, so compiler doesn't have to generate a default destructor.

Comment: No the c++ won't compile - try it. There may be a definition for `B` somewhere but the unique_ptr doesn't know that.