# How to destruct a singleton instance, or why the follow code works for destructor?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, parallel-processing

the following code used to delete a singleton instance, why the works before delete is necessary?

```
// @brief Destruct the singleton instance
// @note Only work with gcc/clang
__attribute__((destructor)) static void delete_() {
    //works before delete
    typedef char T_must_be_complete[sizeof(T) == 0 ? -1 : 1];
    (void) sizeof(T_must_be_complete);
    delete instance_;
}
```

Comment: while T is the template typename template<typename T>, and instance_ = new T()

Answer (score 1):

This is a delete that first checks whether the type is complete. Similar to [`boost::checked_delete`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/core/doc/html/core/checked_delete.html).

The idea of it is to generate a compilation error when attempting to delete an [incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) ([which has a good chance of causing undefined behavior, depending on the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517245/why-really-deleting-an-incomplete-type-is-undefined-behaviour)).

For example (using `boost::checked_delete` for convenience, since I don't know the specifics of the class of which your `delete_` is a member, but they're basically the same) :

```
struct X;

void foo(X* x) {
    boost::checked_delete(x);
}
```

Note that a regular `delete x;` might cause a warning from the compiler (depending on your compiler), but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: I wonder why a simple `(void)sizeof(T);` didn't cut it -- are there versions of GCC or Clang that will return `0` for an incomplete type?

Comment: @Quentin : I can't speak for the OP's code, but for `boost::checked_delete` which is very similar, the complexity was added to cover for a CodeWarrior 8 bug : [commit](https://github.com/boostorg/core/commit/e6d3d3dbb188bd5d6aac6e97c7609efa3494e282#diff-bf75d3e38756c220413f469204c9864e), [mailing list](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/08/51558.php)

Comment: oh, and the Intel 7 compiler : [commit](https://github.com/boostorg/core/commit/82aa7bfcbc140a8dbfdc2c86643df1977ccdb17c), [mailing list](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/07/49958.php)